# Approximation of angle relationships in arbitrary triangle

Tags: trigonometry, approximation

I am trying to approximate the expression

$\sin \varphi_s - \sin \varphi_e = 2 \cos\left(\frac{\varphi_s + \varphi_e}{2}\right) \sin\left(\frac{\varphi_s-\varphi_e}{2}\right)$

to include the angle $\theta_s = \arctan \left(\frac{x_m}{y_m}\right)$ .

Hereby an image of what I mean:
[image: as shown in this diagram]

Of course we also know that

$\sin \varphi_s = \frac{x_m + \frac{L}{2}}{\sqrt{(x_m + \frac{L}{2})^2 + y_m^2}}
= \frac{r_m \sin\theta_s + \frac{L}{2}}{\sqrt{(r_m\sin\theta_s + \frac{L}{2})^2 + r_m^2\cos^2\theta_s}}
= \frac{r_m \sin\theta_s + \frac{L}{2}}{\sqrt{r_m^2 + L r_m \sin\theta_s + \frac{L^2}{4}}}$

and similarly

$\sin \varphi_e = \frac{x_m - \frac{L}{2}}{\sqrt{(x_m - \frac{L}{2})^2 + y_m^2}}
= \frac{r_m \sin\theta_s - \frac{L}{2}}{\sqrt{(r_m\sin\theta_s - \frac{L}{2})^2 + r_m^2\cos^2\theta_s}}
= \frac{r_m \sin\theta_s - \frac{L}{2}}{\sqrt{r_m^2 - L r_m \sin\theta_s + \frac{L^2}{4}}}$,

where $L$ is highlighted in red in the diagram.
I know that a good approximation for $L \ll r_m \land \theta_s \approx 0$ is obviously

$\sin \varphi_s - \sin \varphi_e \approx \frac{L}{\sqrt{x_m^2 + y_m^2}} = \frac{L}{r_m}$.

I also know from playing around with some numerical examples that

$\sin \varphi_s - \sin \varphi_e \approx \frac{L \cos^2 \theta_s}{r_m}$

is a good approximation for $L \ll r_m$ and a wide range of angles $\theta_s$, however I have trouble proving it using the expressions/fractions shown above. I've tried approximating the resulting triangles by two right triangles with height $r_m$ and base given by a projection of $L$ but I can't seem to simplify the expressions far enough to be useful.

Is there a straightforward way of arriving at the $\cos^2 \theta_s$ expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\sin\theta_s$ is small, there is the standard expansion of the two terms in their Taylor series around $\sin \theta_s=0$:
$$
\sin\varphi_s - \sin\varphi_e
=
\frac{r_m\sin\theta_s+L/2}{\sqrt{r_m^2+Lr_m\sin\theta_s+L^2/4}}
-\frac{r_m\sin\theta_s-L/2}{\sqrt{r_m^2-Lr_m\sin\theta_s+L^2/4}}
$$
$$
= \frac{2L}{\sqrt{4r_m^2+L^2}}
- \frac{4r_m^2L(8r_m^2-L^2)}{(4r_m^2+L^2)^{5/2}}\sin^2\theta_s
$$
$$
- \frac{20r_m^4L^3(16r_m^2-3L^2)}{(4r_m^2+L^2)^{9/2}}\sin^4\theta_s
- \frac{168r_m^6L^5(24r_m^2-5L^2)}{(4r_m^2+L^2)^{13/2}}\sin^6\theta_s
-\cdots
$$
This is a sequence with a quite regular growth pattern in all the coefficients.
The integers 4, 20, 168, 1716,... in the numerator are 4 times the Catalan
numbers of https://oeis.org/A024492 .
One can substitute $\sin^{2i}\theta_s=(1-\cos^2\theta_s)^i$ to obtain a series of $\cos\theta_s$.

Alternatively one can use a taylor series in  terms of $L/r_m$:
$$
\sin\varphi_s - \sin\varphi_e
\approx
\cos^2\theta_s (L/r_m)
+\frac{1}{8}\cos^2\theta_s (5\sin^2\theta_s-1)(L/r_m)^3
$$
$$
+\frac{3}{128}\cos^2\theta_s (21\sin^4\theta_s-14\sin^2\theta_s+1)(L/r_m)^5
+O((L/r_m)^7)
$$

Comment: While I'm sure this brute-force approach does work, it lacks the elegance / simplicity of the simple formula that empirically I know works much better than the second order approximation given above.
Also where does $\sin^2 \theta_s$ come from? Is this because for small $\theta_s$ we have $\theta_s^2 \approx \sin^2 \theta_s$?

Comment: $\sin^2\theta_s$ comes from the fact that both $\sin\varphi_s$ and $\sin\varphi_e$ are functions of $\sin\theta_s$. There is no small angle approximation of that sine in my formula.